# Beautiful Soup returns a element tag but treats it like a NoneType

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With the help of BeautifulSoup I am looping through the rows of a table. Each row has multiple anchor elements and I want to get the value of the first one.

A single row looks like this

```html
<tr> 
    <td>155</td>
    <td><img alt="yada" src="yada"/> <a href="yada">Genesect</a></td>
    <td><a href="yada"><img alt="Kaefer" src="yada"/></a> <a href="yada"><img alt="Stahl" src="yada"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

So this is my loop and how I try to get the value of the first anchor element

```py
for row in pkmn_rows:
    name_anchor = row.find('a')
    name = name_anchor.'???'
```

With `row.find('a)` I get the first anchor element, so that is `<a href="yada">Genesect</a></td>` - I verified that with print statements. Even the type of name_anchor is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.

So it should not be that hard to extract only the text value. I looked into the documentation and googled around and found couple of possible solutions, like:

- `name_anchour.text`
- `name_anchour.string`
- `name_anchour.value`
- `name_anchour.contents[0]`

But nothing works, as everytime I become the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(name_anchor.string)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

As I understand, 'NoneType' indicates that name_anchor is null, but that cannot be true, as various print statements show the content and the type.

Am I making a silly mistake?

Comment: can you share the actual link?

Comment: Actual link to webpage I am scrapping: https://www.bisafans.de/pokedex/listen/regionaldex.php?dex=einall

Comment: There are some 'None` elements coming with the links. I'm off to dinner..will check it once I'm back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find all the rows from the table via `pkmn_rows = page.findAll("tr")`, it returns even the `<tr><th>..</th></tr>` row. This doesn't have an anchor element and it leads to the error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'`

To get the names from the rows, you can use the index like this inside your `for` loop `pkmn_rows[1:]`

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(<insert_url_here>)
page = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
pkmn_rows = page.findAll("tr")

for row in pkmn_rows[1:]:
    name_anchor = row.find("a")
    print(name_anchor.string)
```

Comment: That worked - so the mistake was in the first row element, which truly was empty. Clean code would have helped, if I only would have made an if check if row returns an <a> element. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please consider upvoting or approving the answer if this helped :)